# MS-Access Query to PostgreSQL View

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access, sum, case

I am converting a microsoft access query into a postgresql view. The query has obvious components that I have found reasonable answers to. However, I am still stuck on getting the final result:

```
SELECT All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID,
    Sum(IIf([Type]="LODE",IIf([Status]="Active",1,0),0)) AS LD_Actv, 
    Sum(IIf([Type]="LODE",IIf([Loc_Date]>#8/31/2017#,IIf([Loc_Date]<#9/1/2018#,1,0),0),0)) AS LD_stkd_17_18, 
    Sum(IIf([Type]="LODE",IIf([Loc_Date]>#8/31/2016#,IIf([Loc_Date]<#9/1/2017#,1,0),0),0)) AS LD_stkd_16_17,
    Sum(IIf([Type]="LODE",IIf([Loc_Date]<#1/1/1910#,IIf(IsNull([Clsd_Date]),1,(IIf([Clsd_Date]>#1/1/1900#,1,0))),0),0)) AS Actv_1900s, 
    Sum(IIf([Type]="LODE",IIf([Loc_Date]<#1/1/1920#,IIf(IsNull([Clsd_Date]),1,(IIf([Clsd_Date]>#1/1/1910#,1,0))),0),0)) AS Actv_1910s,
  FROM All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID,
  GROUP BY All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID,
  HAVING (((Sum(IIf([casetype_txt]="LODE",1,0)))>0));
```

Realizing I need to use CASE SUM WHEN, here is what I have worked out so far:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW hgeditor.vw_test AS
     SELECT All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID,
     SUM (CASE WHEN(Type='LODE' AND WHEN(Status='Active',1,0),0)) AS LD_Actv, 
     SUM (CASE WHEN(Type='LODE' AND WHEN(Loc_Date>'8/31/2017' AND Loc_Date<'9/1/2018',1,0),0),0)) AS LD_stkd_17_18,
     SUM (CASE WHEN(Type='LODE' AND WHEN(Loc_Date<'1/1/1910' AND (IsNull(Clsd_Date),1,(WHEN([Clsd_Date]>'1/1/1900',1,0))),0),0)) AS Actv_1900s
    FROM All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID,
    GROUP BY All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID,
    HAVING (((SUM(IIf(Type='LODE',1,0)))>0));
```

The goal is to count the number of instances in which the Sec_ID has the following:

- has (Type = LODE and Status = Active) = SUM integer
- has (Type = LODE and Loc_Date between 8/31/2017 and 9/1/2018) = SUM Integer

My primary issue is getting a SUM integer to populate in the new columns

Comment: `when` is not a function, a case expression is formed like this: `case when ... then when ... then ... else ... end` You seem to be using when like an `IF()`

Comment: @Used_By_Already I was using this example as a reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111280/sumcase-when-resulting-in-multiple-rows-of-the-selection)

Comment: yes, that reference is ok, but this is not `CASE WHEN(Type='LODE' AND WHEN(Status='Active',1,0),0))`

Comment: So, essentially I don't know what my 'THEN' statement would look like.....

Comment: Read my answer, below. You are actually just returning 1 or 0s in the original, so `THEN 1 ELSE 0`

Comment: @Used_By_Already 'SUM (CASE WHEN Type ='LODE' AND Status = 'Active' THEN.....) AS ld_actv,' .......but THEN what?

Comment: sigh, really, could you look down, try it, then ask

Comment: sorry...I am working on it, looking at your comments responding, then messing with it more....sometimes your comment hasn't shown up by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case expressions are the equivalent to the Access IIF() functions, but `WHEN` isn't a function so it isn't used by passing a set of parameters. Think of it as being a tiny where clause instead, it evaluates one or more predicates to determine what to do, and the action taken is established by what you specify after `THEN`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW hgeditor.vw_test AS
SELECT
    All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID
  , SUM( CASE
        WHEN TYPE = 'LODE' AND
            STATUS = 'Active' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END ) AS LD_Actv
  , SUM( CASE
        WHEN TYPE = 'LODE' AND
            Loc_Date > to_date('08/31/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') AND
            Loc_Date < to_date('09/1/2018','mm/dd/yyyy')  THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END ) AS LD_stkd_17_18
  , SUM( CASE
        WHEN TYPE = 'LODE' AND
            Loc_Date < to_date('1/1/1910','mm/dd/yyyy')  AND
            [Clsd_Date] > to_date('1/1/1900','mm/dd/yyyy')  THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END ) AS Actv_1900s
FROM All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID
GROUP BY
    All_Claim_Data.Sec_ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE
    WHEN Type = 'LODE' THEN 1
END ) > 0
;
```

By the way, you should NOT be relying on MM/DD/YYYY as dates in Postgres

**nb:** Aggregate functions ignore NULL, take this example:

```
+----------+
| id value |
+----------+
| 1  x     |
| 2  NULL  |
| 3  x     |
| 4  NULL  |
| 5  x     |
+----------+

select
       count(*)      c_all
     , count(value)  c_value
from t

+-------+----------+
| c_all |  c_value |
+-------+----------+
|     5 |        3 |
+-------+----------+


select
       sum(case when value IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) sum_case
     , count(case when value IS NOT NULL then 1 end)      count_case
from t

+----------+-------------+
| sum_case |  count_case |
+----------+-------------+
|        3 |           3 |
+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: please ask about this answer here

Comment: Note that in Postgres `sum(case when value IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)` can also be written as `count(*) filter (where value is not null)` - I find that more obvious to understand

Comment: It is not proven to be "more obvious" as that is a subjective assessment. To me, using sum() to achieve a count is even less obvious, no matter how you reword the case expression.

Comment: Well, my expression does use `count(*)` to count.

Comment: Yes, and for that it is "more obvious" in my view. I suspect we agree on rhat. The filter syntax is less obvious I  think. But thank you for reminding us of the alternative.